# Make a slider responsive (jQuery)

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I have a slider, I want to make them responsive the problem is the size of slider is into the jQuery file

sow how I can edit the code ?

code of jQuery

```js
(function( window, $, undefined ) {

 var $event = $.event, resizeTimeout;

 $event.special.smartresize  = {
  setup: function() {
   $(this).bind( "resize", $event.special.smartresize.handler );
  },
  teardown: function() {
   $(this).unbind( "resize", $event.special.smartresize.handler );
  },
  handler: function( event, execAsap ) {
   // Save the context
   var context = this,
    args  = arguments;

   // set correct event type
   event.type = "smartresize";

   if ( resizeTimeout ) { clearTimeout( resizeTimeout ); }
   resizeTimeout = setTimeout(function() {
    jQuery.event.handle.apply( context, args );
   }, execAsap === "execAsap"? 0 : 100 );
  }
 };

 $.fn.smartresize    = function( fn ) {
  return fn ? this.bind( "smartresize", fn ) : this.trigger( "smartresize", ["execAsap"] );
 };
 
 $.Slideshow     = function( options, element ) {
 
  this.$el   = $( element );
  
  /***** images ****/
  
  // list of image items
  this.$list   = this.$el.find('ul.ei-slider-large');
  // image items
  this.$imgItems  = this.$list.children('li');
  // total number of items
  this.itemsCount  = this.$imgItems.length;
  // images
  this.$images  = this.$imgItems.find('img:first');
  
  /***** thumbs ****/
  
  // thumbs wrapper
  this.$sliderthumbs = this.$el.find('ul.ei-slider-thumbs').hide();
  // slider elements
  this.$sliderElems = this.$sliderthumbs.children('li');
  // sliding div
  this.$sliderElem = this.$sliderthumbs.children('li.ei-slider-element');
  // thumbs
  this.$thumbs  = this.$sliderElems.not('.ei-slider-element');
  
  // initialize slideshow
  this._init( options );
  
 };
 
 $.Slideshow.defaults   = {
  // animation types:
  // "sides" : new slides will slide in from left / right
  // "center": new slides will appear in the center
  animation   : 'center', // sides || center
  // if true the slider will automatically slide, and it will only stop if the user clicks on a thumb
  autoplay   : false,
  // interval for the slideshow
  slideshow_interval : 3000,
  // speed for the sliding animation
  speed   : 800,
  // easing for the sliding animation
  easing   : '',
  // percentage of speed for the titles animation. Speed will be speed * titlesFactor
  titlesFactor  : 0.60,
  // titles animation speed
  titlespeed   : 800,
  // titles animation easing
  titleeasing   : '',

    };
 
 $.Slideshow.prototype   = {
  _init     : function( options ) {
   
   this.options   = $.extend( true, {}, $.Slideshow.defaults, options );
   
   // set the opacity of the title elements and the image items
   this.$imgItems.css( 'opacity', 0 );
   this.$imgItems.find('div.ei-title > *').css( 'opacity', 0 );
   
   // index of current visible slider
   this.current  = 0;
   
   var _self   = this;
   
   // preload images
   // add loading status
   this.$loading  = $('<div class="ei-slider-loading">Loading</div>').prependTo( _self.$el );
   
   $.when( this._preloadImages() ).done( function() {
    
    // hide loading status
    _self.$loading.hide();
    
    // calculate size and position for each image
    _self._setImagesSize();
    
    // configure thumbs container
    _self._initThumbs();
    
    // show first
    _self.$imgItems.eq( _self.current ).css({
     'opacity'  : 1,
     'z-index' : 10
    }).show().find('div.ei-title > *').css( 'opacity', 1 );
    
    // if autoplay is true
    if( _self.options.autoplay ) {
    
     _self._startSlideshow();
    
    }
    
    // initialize the events
    _self._initEvents();
   
   });
   
  },
  _preloadImages  : function() {
   
   // preloads all the large images
   
   var _self = this,
    loaded = 0;
   
   return $.Deferred(
   
    function(dfd) {
   
     _self.$images.each( function( i ) {
      
      $('<img/>').load( function() {
      
       if( ++loaded === _self.itemsCount ) {
       
        dfd.resolve();
        
       }
      
      }).attr( 'src', $(this).attr('src') );
     
     });
     
    }
    
   ).promise();
   
  },
  _setImagesSize  : function() {
   
   // save ei-slider's width
   this.elWidth = this.$el.width();
   
   var _self = this;
   
   this.$images.each( function( i ) {
    
    var $img = $(this);
     imgDim = _self._getImageDim( $img.attr('src') );
     
    $img.css({
     width  : imgDim.width,
     height  : imgDim.height,
     marginLeft : imgDim.left,
     marginTop : imgDim.top
    });
    
   });
  
  },
  _getImageDim : function( src ) {
   
   var $img    = new Image();
       
   $img.src    = src;
     
   var c_w  = this.elWidth,
    c_h  = this.$el.height(),
    r_w  = c_h / c_w,
    
    i_w  = $img.width,
    i_h  = $img.height,
    r_i  = i_h / i_w,
    new_w, new_h, new_left, new_top;
     
   if( r_w > r_i ) {
    
    new_h = c_h;
    new_w = c_h / r_i;
   
   }
   else {
   
    new_h = c_w * r_i;
    new_w = c_w;
   
   }
     
   return {
    width : new_w,
    height : new_h,
    left : ( c_w - new_w ) / 2,
    top  : ( c_h - new_h ) / 2
   };
  
  },
  _initThumbs   : function() {
  
   // set the max-width of the slider elements to the one set in the plugin's options
   // also, the width of each slider element will be 100% / total number of elements
   this.$sliderElems.css({
    'width'  : 100 / this.itemsCount + '%'
   });
   
   // set the max-width of the slider and show it
   this.$sliderthumbs.css( 'width', this.options.thumbMaxWidth * this.itemsCount + 'px' ).show();
   
  },
  _startSlideshow  : function() {
  
   var _self = this;
   
   this.slideshow = setTimeout( function() {
    
    var pos;
    
    ( _self.current === _self.itemsCount - 1 ) ? pos = 0 : pos = _self.current + 1;
    
    _self._slideTo( pos );
    
    if( _self.options.autoplay ) {
    
     _self._startSlideshow();
    
    }
   
   }, this.options.slideshow_interval);
  
  },
  // shows the clicked thumb's slide
  _slideTo   : function( pos ) {
   
   // return if clicking the same element or if currently animating
   if( pos === this.current || this.isAnimating )
    return false;
   
   this.isAnimating = true;
   
   var $currentSlide = this.$imgItems.eq( this.current ),
    $nextSlide  = this.$imgItems.eq( pos ),
    _self   = this,
    
    preCSS   = {zIndex : 10},
    animCSS   = {opacity : 1};
   
   // new slide will slide in from left or right side
   if( this.options.animation === 'sides' ) {
    
    preCSS.left  = ( pos > this.current ) ? -1 * this.elWidth : this.elWidth;
    animCSS.left = 0;
   
   } 
   
   // titles animation
   $nextSlide.find('div.ei-title > h2')
       .css( 'margin-right', 50 + 'px' )
       .stop()
       .delay( this.options.speed * this.options.titlesFactor )
       .animate({ marginRight : 0 + 'px', opacity : 1 }, this.options.titlespeed, this.options.titleeasing )
       .end()
       .find('div.ei-title > h3')
       .css( 'margin-right', -50 + 'px' )
       .stop()
       .delay( this.options.speed * this.options.titlesFactor )
       .animate({ marginRight : 0 + 'px', opacity : 1 }, this.options.titlespeed, this.options.titleeasing )
   
   $.when(
    
    // fade out current titles
    $currentSlide.css( 'z-index' , 1 ).find('div.ei-title > *').stop().fadeOut( this.options.speed / 2, function() {
     // reset style
     $(this).show().css( 'opacity', 0 ); 
    }),
    
    // animate next slide in
    $nextSlide.css( preCSS ).stop().animate( animCSS, this.options.speed, this.options.easing ),
    
    // "sliding div" moves to new position
    this.$sliderElem.stop().animate({
     left : this.$thumbs.eq( pos ).position().left
    }, this.options.speed )
    
   ).done( function() {
    
    // reset values
    $currentSlide.css( 'opacity' , 0 ).find('div.ei-title > *').css( 'opacity', 0 );
     _self.current = pos;
     _self.isAnimating  = false;
    
    });
    
  },
  _initEvents   : function() {
   
   var _self = this;
   
   // window resize
   $(window).on( 'smartresize.eislideshow', function( event ) {
    
    // resize the images
    _self._setImagesSize();
   
    // reset position of thumbs sliding div
    _self.$sliderElem.css( 'left', _self.$thumbs.eq( _self.current ).position().left );
   
   });
   
   // click the thumbs
   this.$thumbs.on( 'click.eislideshow', function( event ) {
    
    if( _self.options.autoplay ) {
    
     clearTimeout( _self.slideshow );
     _self.options.autoplay = false;
    
    }
    
    var $thumb = $(this),
     idx  = $thumb.index() - 1; // exclude sliding div
     
    _self._slideTo( idx );
    
    return false;
   
   });
   
  }
 };
 
 var logError     = function( message ) {
  
  if ( this.console ) {
   
   console.error( message );
   
  }
  
 };
 
 $.fn.eislideshow   = function( options ) {
 
  if ( typeof options === 'string' ) {
  
   var args = Array.prototype.slice.call( arguments, 1 );

   this.each(function() {
   
    var instance = $.data( this, 'eislideshow' );
    
    if ( !instance ) {
     logError( "cannot call methods on eislideshow prior to initialization; " +
     "attempted to call method '" + options + "'" );
     return;
    }
    
    if ( !$.isFunction( instance[options] ) || options.charAt(0) === "_" ) {
     logError( "no such method '" + options + "' for eislideshow instance" );
     return;
    }
    
    instance[ options ].apply( instance, args );
   
   });
  
  } 
  else {
  
   this.each(function() {
   
    var instance = $.data( this, 'eislideshow' );
    if ( !instance ) {
     $.data( this, 'eislideshow', new $.Slideshow( options, this ) );
    }
   
   });
  
  }
  
  return this;
  
 };
 
})( window, jQuery );
```

How I can edit that to make them responsive ? can you give an example ?

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you use something more simple (only 3 steps) instead of review this code.

Code:

**Step 1: Link required files**

First and most important, the jQuery library needs to be included (no need to download - link directly from Google). Next, download the package from this site and link the bxSlider CSS file (for the theme) and the bxSlider Javascript file.

```
<!-- jQuery library (served from Google) -->
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!-- bxSlider Javascript file -->
<script src="/js/jquery.bxslider.min.js"></script>
<!-- bxSlider CSS file -->
<link href="/lib/jquery.bxslider.css" rel="stylesheet" />
```

**Step 2: Create HTML markup**

Create a `<ul class="bxslider">` element, with a `<li>` for each slide. Slides can contain images, video, or any other HTML content!

```
<ul class="bxslider">
  <li><img src="/images/pic1.jpg" /></li>
  <li><img src="/images/pic2.jpg" /></li>
  <li><img src="/images/pic3.jpg" /></li>
  <li><img src="/images/pic4.jpg" /></li>
</ul>
```

**Step 3: Call the bxSlider**

Call .bxslider() on `<ul class="bxslider">`. Note that the call must be made inside of a $(document).ready() call, or the plugin will not work!

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('.bxslider').bxSlider();
});
```

I really believe, this will be more helpful and simple.

**Credits:** http://bxslider.com

**Different configurations**

```
$('.bxslider').bxSlider({
   mode: 'fade',
   captions: true,
   pagerCustom: '#bx-pager',
   adaptiveHeight: true,
   slideWidth: 150
});
```

Don't forget to read this: http://bxslider.com/options

Comment: I have a slider and it work, but I want to make my website responsive, but I have a problem. because the jQuery file has width and height,So I need to know how to edit width in jQuery file

Comment: Sorry, but i need to ask you...Why you not replace for a new with everythin ? I mean... the code of bxSlider it's done! They have responsive system and effects to apply. Why you are trying recreate you own code? I dont know how much time you spent but, in your case i believe, we don't need reinvent the wheel. We can use it to create the things more fast and well. Thats why we use jQuery for example. Please consider this comment with only a suggestion, i'm just trying to help. Cheers!

Comment: I have two slider's, not responsive, so, I want to make them responsive, If you want to give me your gmail to send to you the code for see the slider
when I make it this function $(document).ready(function(){
  $('.bxslider').bxSlider();
}); 

in my code ?

Comment: The slider that you give to me is very cool, I need a responsive slider for make pictures of players I have one but it's not responsive

Comment: I glad to you that understanded my point of view. So, if you need the new slider, you can just apply the bxSlider in different size of pictures, not the problem. Create your list of pictures with (UL>LI, for example) and use this. I'll put settings in my comment.

Comment: What the status of issue? If you dont have more questions, please mark resolved. Thanks